# django, static files not found 404

Tags: django, nginx

I am getting an error with static files in nginx

```
custom_main.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

THis is my nginx config:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 94.154.13.214;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/django_direct/main_app/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass unix: /root/django_direct/django_direct.sock;
    }
}
```

What do I do?

---

upd: `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main_app/static')
# ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main_app/static')
```

Comment: What are your static settings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman see update

Comment: did you run collect static?, also check to make sure you used the {% load_static %} tag in your template

Comment: So if your static files are in main_app/static, why is your nginx static location pointing to somewhere completely different?

Comment: @DanielRoseman founded this error and changed it, got  another error, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584980/nginx-invalid-number-of-arguments-in-proxy-pass-directive