# nginx invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive

Tags: django, nginx

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django_direct:12
```

My nginx conf  file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 94.154.13.214;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/django_direct/main_app/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass unix: /root/django_direct/django_direct.sock;
    }
}
```

What do I do?
**UPD:**
I have changed file like this:

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/root/django_direct/django_direct.sock;
```

But didn't help, I've restarted nginx and now
I am getting now a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: What is `unix:` doing here? Shouldn't this be all in one path?

Comment: You have an extra shave between unix: and the rest of the path.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  see upd

Comment: @user2950593: you get the exact same error?

Comment: @user2950593: did you restart the nginx server?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , oh I have restarted it, and got error: 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: @user2950593: it looks to me that this is another error, so perhaps it is better to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 44):

If someone else finds this and has this error.  Check that you have a semi-colon at the end of the parameters line.  goes for all of the lines, not just proxy_pass.

Answer (score 4):

Well the nginx sees two parameters: `unix`, and `/root/django_redirect/...`. I have the idea however that you want to specify a UNIX domain socket path. You can do this with:

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/root/django_direct/django_direct.sock;
```

As is described in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is wrong.
It needs an URL:

> Sets the protocol and address of a proxied server and an optional URI to which a location should be mapped. As a protocol, “http” or “https” can be specified. The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address, and an optional port:
>
> proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/uri/;
>
> or as a UNIX-domain socket path specified after the word “unix” and enclosed in  colons:
>
> proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/backend.socket:/uri/;

See the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

I can also happen when **you mistakenly put a `=` character** in, trying to assign a value that way.

```
proxy_pass = http://other_node;
```

The same thing might happen to you with for example `auth_basic = "restricted site"`.

Just remove the `=`.