# Nginx proxy_pass :"invalid number of arguments using http://app_server; or http:/x.x.x.x:8000/uri/;

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx, django and gunicorn and I keep getting the error invalid number of arguments on the proxy_pass line in my nginx sites-enabled configuration. I believe this is the correct way as per the nginx documentation. Where am I going wrong? I am really stuck.

```
upstream app_server{
   server xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
location @proxy_to_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;   

    }
```

I checked the following solution@[similar question][1] but it doesn't answer why the configuration above is not working[1]:[nginx invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584980/nginx-invalid-number-of-arguments-in-proxy-pass-directive).
I even tried using proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000; still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by adding ; to $hppt_host

Answer (score -2):

This is how I solved it. I added proxy_pass and proxy_redirect off first before the other parameters.

```
location @proxy_to_app {
          proxy_pass http://app_server;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
```

Comment: The order does not matter. You've solved your problem in some other way.