# How to connect to a minikube cluster created in a linux VM from windows 10 local computer?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, minikube

I have created a following minikube cluster in linux machine . Now I wanted to connect to the node of the cluster from my local windows 10 machine. I have kubectl installed in the local machine. How do I connect the worker node of a minikube cluster from my windows machine? I am new to the Kubes , please let me know if any details needs to added to the question.

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube       Ready    control-plane,master   52d   v1.22.3
minikube-m02   Ready    worker                 49m   v1.22.3
minikube-m03   Ready    worker                 43m   v1.22.3
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a Nginx reverse proxy in front of a minikube can make us interact from local machines to the Virtual machine where the minikube is installed.

You can’t access minikube remotely because it’s only accessible locally. For this reason, you need to deploy an Nginx reverse proxy next to minikube that will allow receiving requests from remote clients then forward them to kube-apiserver. Kubernetes API server is a point where all your requests will go when you use the command-line tool kubectl. The kubectl allows you to run commands against Kubernetes clusters.

Refer this [document](https://faun.pub/accessing-a-remote-minikube-from-a-local-computer-fd6180dd66dd) for the detailed procedure of installing Nginx reverse proxy in front of a minikube.

Comment: @nikitha, my docker fails to start,it shows the error nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/minikube.conf:9 , Could you help a bit , the content of the file is, server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    auth_basic "Administrator's Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://`minikube ip`:8443;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/minikube-client.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/minikube-client.key;
  }
}

Comment: @nikitha, I get the below error as well when hardcoding the minikube_ip to ip in the ~/.kube/config file, error : nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/minikube-client.crt": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE). Though there isnt any minikube-client.crt file in that specified location. Kindly help

Comment: @JCDani, For **error mentioned in the 1st comment:** Check that you have a semicolon at the end of the parameters line. Refer this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584980/nginx-invalid-number-of-arguments-in-proxy-pass-directive) for more workarounds on error1 and **For error in 2nd comment:** it seems there are some bad
characters which are failing the decode process on routers. Use this command `openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem` to find any errors in the certificate.